# Finding unconnected polylines and connecting them using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, convert

I have a pipeline network, during manual digitization have a lot pipes unconnect.

Is there any way to find pipes unconnect and edit it in QGIS?

Comment: you can use the "Topology Checker" Plugin for that. see also: https://www.geodose.com/2017/09/how-to-check-topology-error-in-qgis.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html) tool under GRASS from Processing toolbox, search for v.clean in the toolbox and you will find it. Use the pipeline network as an input file and under the tools select `Snap` option with a threshold value that you need to specify based on the distance of the disconnected vertices. You need to experiment by yourself to select the proper value.